# Como puedo ocultar un input según el valor que traiga otro input desde la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

como puedo esconder un **input**  según la información que traiga otro input desde la base de datos.

Ejemplo: tengo el detalle de un producto el cual tiene 2 categorías "Accesorios y vacunas", si la categoría es vacuna que me muestre un input, de lo contrario no me lo muestre.

Muchas gracias, espero me puedan ayudar.

---

mira este es mi código, digamos que funciona a la mitad ya que para que me capture el dato tengo que dar click sobre el input categoría.

```
**$('#categoria').focusout(function() { var x = $(this).val(); if (x == 'Vacuna '){ $('.indicacionesContra').show(); $('.edades').show(); alert("Campos mostrandocen"+ x); }else{ $('.indicacionesContra').hide(); $('.edades').hide(); alert("Campos nada" + x); } });**
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes verificar si el valor que has obtenido de la BD es 'vacuna'

```
<?php if($valor_bd == 'vacuna'){ ?>
      <input type= 'text' value= <?= $valor_bd ?> >
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hola, mira este es mi código, digamos que funciona a la mitad ya que para que me capture el dato tengo que dar click sobre el input categoría.

 $('#categoria').focusout(function() {
  var x = $(this).val();
  
     if (x == 'Vacuna '){
  $('.indicacionesContra').show();
  $('.edades').show();
   alert("Campos mostrandocen"+ x);
  }else{
  $('.indicacionesContra').hide();
  $('.edades').hide();
  alert("Campos nada" + x);
   
  }
    });